# mongodb c# driver join query

Tags: c#, mongodb

```
public class Person
{
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    public int AddressID { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public Person Father { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public double Income { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public class Address
{
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    public int HouseNo { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
}
```

How do I get Sum of Income  by street? by using mongodb c# driver

Got income by Age.

```
var personcollection = this.cdb.GetCollection<Person>("person");
var aggregate = personcollection.Aggregate()
            .Group(new BsonDocument { { "_id", "$Age" }, { "sum", new BsonDocument("$sum", "$Income") } });
 var results = await aggregate.ToListAsync();
```

but I have know Idea  how to link two documents for a single query.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: MongoDB has no joins so you would need to change your schema to embed Address in Person instead of using a reference.

Comment: is there no way to do this?

Comment: Not in a single query, no.

Answer (score 1):

This smells like a schema design flaw.

You should embed your address document into your `Person` document:

```
public class Person
{
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public Person Father { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public double Income { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public class Address
{
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    public int HouseNo { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
}
```

You can then easily perform the requested query
(to modify your existing query)

```
var personcollection = this.cdb.GetCollection<Person>("person");
var aggregate = personcollection.Aggregate()
            .Group(new BsonDocument { { "_id", "$Address.Street" }, { "sum", new BsonDocument("$sum", "$Income") } });
 var results = await aggregate.ToListAsync();
```

Notice the use of dot notation to reach inside embedded documents - `Address.Street`

Comment: I know this can be done. I need to know if this can be done without  embedding the address field inside the person.

Comment: What is addresses are pre-defined? Are we then going to have a collection with Address documents, aswell as having the Address documents embedded on persons?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old thread - but I was composing a question relating to 'lookup' and I found this.  If someone arrives by way of search, it's worth noting that the plumbing is now in place for 'joins' in MongoDB.

If you have the proper MongoDB and driver versions (3.2 and 2.2, respectively - I think), then you can use 'lookup' in the aggregation pipeline to join the two tables on ID.

Answer (score 0):

I did lookup this way:

**MongoDB**

```
db.dbACESSO.aggregate([

{$match: {PartnerId: "2021", CD_CLIENTE: 4003}},

{$lookup: {from: "GRUPO_UNIDADE", localField: "CD_GRUPO_UNIDADE", foreignField: "CD_GRUPO_UNIDADE", as: "GRUPO"}},
{$lookup:{from: "UNIDADE", localField: "CD_UNIDADE", foreignField: "CD_UNIDADE",as: "UNIDADE"}},

{$unwind: "$GRUPO"},
{$unwind: "$UNIDADE"},

{ $project: { _id: 0, CD_CLIENTE : 1, CD_ACESSO : 1, NOME : 1, EMAIL : 1, FG_KIPER_MOBILE : 1, CD_GRUPO_UNIDADE : 1, CD_UNIDADE : 1, 
    GRUPO: "$GRUPO.NM_DESCRICAO", UNIDADE : "$UNIDADE.NM_DESCRICAO", 
    NU_TELEFONE: { $cond: [{ $eq : ["$NU_TELEFONE", { }] }, "", "$NU_TELEFONE"] }, 
    TAG: { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$NU_KIPER_TAG", { }] }, 0, 1] }, 
    CONTROLE: { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$NU_KIPER_RF", { }] }, 0, 1] }, 
    APPATIVO: { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$KEY_HASH", { }] }, "", "$KEY_HASH"] } } 
}   

])
```

**C# Driver**

```
var match = new BsonDocument { { "$match", new BsonDocument { { "PartnerId", cliente }, { "CD_CLIENTE", codCond } } } };
            var lookup1 = new BsonDocument { { "$lookup", new BsonDocument { { "from", "GRUPO_UNIDADE" }, { "localField", "CD_GRUPO_UNIDADE" }, { "foreignField", "CD_GRUPO_UNIDADE" }, { "as", "GRUPO" } } } };
            var lookup2 = new BsonDocument { { "$lookup", new BsonDocument { { "from", "UNIDADE" }, { "localField", "CD_UNIDADE" }, { "foreignField", "CD_UNIDADE" }, { "as", "UNIDADE" } } } };
            var unwind1 = new BsonDocument("$unwind", "$GRUPO");
            var unwind2 = new BsonDocument("$unwind", "$UNIDADE");

            var project = new BsonDocument
            {
                {
                    "$project", new BsonDocument
                    {
                        { "_id", 0},
                        { "CD_CLIENTE", 1},
                        { "CD_ACESSO", 1 },
                        { "NOME", 1},
                        { "EMAIL", 1 },
                        { "FG_KIPER_MOBILE", 1 },
                        { "CD_GRUPO_UNIDADE", 1 },
                        { "CD_UNIDADE", 1 },
                        { "GRUPO", "$GRUPO.NM_DESCRICAO" },
                        { "UNIDADE", "$UNIDADE.NM_DESCRICAO" },                        
                        { "NU_TELEFONE", new BsonDocument{{ "$cond", new BsonArray{new BsonDocument{{"$eq", new BsonArray{ "$NU_TELEFONE", new BsonDocument { } } }}, "","$NU_TELEFONE" } }}},
                        { "TAG", new BsonDocument{{ "$cond", new BsonArray{new BsonDocument{{"$eq", new BsonArray{ "$NU_KIPER_TAG", new BsonDocument { } } }}, 0, 1 } }}},
                        { "CONTROLE", new BsonDocument{{ "$cond", new BsonArray{new BsonDocument{{"$eq", new BsonArray{ "$NU_KIPER_RF", new BsonDocument { } } }}, 0, 1 } }}},
                        { "APP", new BsonDocument{{ "$cond", new BsonArray{new BsonDocument{{"$eq", new BsonArray{ "$FG_KIPER_MOBILE", false } }}, 0, 1 } }}},
                        { "APPATIVO", new BsonDocument{{ "$cond", new BsonArray{new BsonDocument{{"$eq", new BsonArray{ "$KEY_HASH", new BsonDocument { } } }}, "", "$KEY_HASH" } }}}
                    }
                }
            };

            var pipeline = new[] { match, lookup1, lookup2, unwind1, unwind2, project };
            var result = collection.Aggregate<BsonDocument>(pipeline).ToList();
            var lista = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UsuariosAcessos>>(result.ToJson()).ToList();
```